# Error writing Files as local user

Tags: c#, windows-10

When attempting to download and write a file as a local user (ie, not run as admin), the following code is throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException(Access to the path is denied.). Originally, I assumed that this was due to the application attempting to write files directly to the C drive. However, I get the same error when attempting to save files to the local user's documents drive, as gotten by this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

This seems to be a windows 10 specific issue, as the application runs fine in previous versions of windows (even writing directly to C:// as a local user, which I had thought would be blocked).

```
private bool DownloadFile(Stream srcStream, string dstFile)
    {
        bool success = false;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        int byteCount;
        FileStream destStream = null;
        try
        {
            destStream = File.Create(dstFile);
            while ((byteCount = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, 16384)) != 0)
            {
                destStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            }
            success = true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return success;
        }
        finally
        {
            try { destStream.Close(); }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

I have checked, and the local user account has full access to their Documents folder, so I'm stumped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Is it running from local application like WPF, etc.. or from ASP.Net?

Comment: It's running as a desktop application.

Comment: Are you running the app/IDE as an administrator?

Comment: You're ignoring any exceptions that you may get, first by using `return success;`, and then by simply ignoring the exception with `{ }`. Why are you doing that when trying to troubleshoot a problem? Why are you **ever** just eating an exception with `{}`? What is the exact value you're receiving in `dstFile` when the function actually executes?

Comment: I'm running it from VS 2013 as a local user (It executes properly when I run VS as an Administrator).

Comment: Make the test executing the .exe directly from the /bin folder

Comment: @Ken: I didn't write this lovely chunk of code, I'm just bug fixing. So far I've only corrected spelling errors. I intend to rearrange things before I finish, but it swallowing exceptions isn't a high priority when I'm stepping through it anyways.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @pix: UnauthorizedAccessException(Access to the path 'snip' is denied.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just did a unit test with your code.

The problem is

```
  destStream = File.Create(dstFile);
```

This is a **folder** not a **file**!

try this:

```
destStream = File.Create(dstFile + "\Test.txt");
```

And tadaaaaa. No more exception ;)

You can not write into a folder. only inside file.

and please use using() when needed :)

Unit test:

```
     [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                var path = Environment.GetFold`enter code here`erPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
// path = "C:\Users\pix\Documents"
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var result = DownloadFile(memoryStream, path);
                    Assert.IsFalse(result);
                    result = DownloadFile(memoryStream, Path.Combine("FILE.txt"));
                    Assert.IsTrue(result);
                }
            }

            private bool DownloadFile(Stream srcStream, string dstFile)
            {
                bool success = false;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                int byteCount;
                FileStream destStream = null;
                try
                {
                    destStream = File.Create(dstFile);
                    while ((byteCount = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, 16384)) != 0)
                    {
                        destStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                    }
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return success;
                }
                finally
                {
                    try { destStream.Close(); }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }

                return success;
            }
```

Comment: If true then IMO the caller needs to fix their call, not that this method needs to assume a folder was passed in. It *appears* that the method assumes the file does not exist, and that the path passed in is not a directory, so IMO the method should just add `if (Directory.Exists(dstFile) || File.Exists(dstFile) || dstFile.EndsWith(Environment.DirectorySeparator.ToString())) { throw new Exception("Method only accepts file paths that do not exist"); }`. Or change the parameter name to `dstFolder` to clarify that it's expecting a folder (then still add validation).

Comment: Eh then at least fix your "unit test" code, which does not have your fix `destStream = File.Create(dstFile + "\Test.txt");` in it, and it also is passing in a file of `path + "test.txt"` which resolves to `"C:\Users\pix\Documentstest.text"`; maybe you meant to `Path.Combine(path, "test.text")`.

Comment: just did from my phone :)

Comment: Well, now I feel like an idiot. In switching it to target the my Documents folder, I forgot to append the filename on the end of the folder path.

Comment: now you can validate the answer :) this can happen when when you are under pressure ;)